# mypy - unable to specify pattern in config file

Tags: mypy

I have a `migrations` folder in my app:

```
$ ls src/migrations/
README          __pycache__     alembic.ini     env.py          script.py.mako  versions
```

And a `mypy` config file:

```
$ cat setup.cfg 
[mypy]
ignore_missing_imports = True
disallow_untyped_calls = True
disallow_incomplete_defs = True

[mypy-*.migrations.*]
ignore_errors = True
```

But when I run

```
mypy src
```

I still see errors from the migrations folder:

```
src/migrations/env.py:95: error: Call to untyped function "run_migrations_offline" in typed context
src/migrations/env.py:97: error: Call to untyped function "run_migrations_online" in typed context
```

why is that and how to fix this?

My version is:

```
$ mypy --version
mypy 0.812
```